# HTML5 Updating Canvas repeating and scaling again

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm just trying to work with a canvas in html5 for the first time and I've come across a problem which I hope is simple to solve but I can't find an answer.

Basically I can draw a shape in the canvas when the document loads, then I want to add some text to it and update the canvas. The canvas starts at scale 0.5 but when I try to add text and redraw the canvas it draws on top of the existing canvas at what I assume is 0.25 scale.

So I believe the canvas is being redrawn on top the of the original canvas and the scale is stacking?

Below is a simplified version of what I'm doing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    playerID = "";
    createCanvas();
}


function createCanvas(){

    var canvas = document.getElementById("player1");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    context.scale(0.5, 0.5);

  //code to draw the shape


    var x = 28;
    var y = 45;
    context.font = "20pt Calibri";
context.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
context.fillText(''+playerID+'', x, y);

  };


function playerNumber(){
 playerID = 5;
 createCanvas();
 }
```

Is there some method of clearing the canvas before I draw it again which will stop this problem, or can I update/refresh the canvas?

I'm not really sure of the proper way to proceed, any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes because you are putting all your code in one function. Big no-no.
Separate it into two sections as follows:

1. Creation:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {            
       var canvas = document.getElementById("player1");
       var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

       context.scale(0.5, 0.5);
   }
   ```
2. Adding text:

   ```
   function playerNumber(){      
       var playerID = 5;  

       var canvas = document.getElementById("player1");
       var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

       var x = 28;
       var y = 45;


       context.font = "20pt Calibri";
       context.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
       context.fillText(''+playerID+'', x, y);

   }
   ```